# regex find query not working when data is a url in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a url field as:

```
db.test.insert({"url":"https://www.google.com/shopping/product/1/online?prds=pid:11247610123343072928,https://www.google.com/shopping/product/1/online?prds=pid:1124761012334307256565"})
```

but when I do

```
db.test.find({"url": {"$regex":"https://www.google.com/shopping/product/1/online?prds=pid:11247610123343072928"}})
```

It returns nothing. I want to find all documents that matches a substring. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to ignore special character and then your query will work.
Try using query below:

```
db.test.find({"url": {"$regex":"https://www.google.com/shopping/product/1/online.*\\?.*prds=pid:11247610123343072928"}})
```